# How to upload pictures to controller

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I save pictures as `byte[]` in the database.
Im familiar with the `HttpPostedFileBase` in asp.net but they got rid of that in .net Core 5 apparently
How can I send the uploaded picture to the controller which converts it into picture and inserts into the database?

```
<input name="UploadedPic" type="file"readonly />
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

C# controller

```
public IActionResult UploadPictures()
    {

        return null;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you have to create ViewModel for upload. and this ViewModel uses your [HttpGet] methods view.And your model should be  `public byte[] Image { get; set; }`  and your ViewModel should be  `public IFormFile Image { get; set; }`

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadPictures([Bind("Image")] ProductVM productVM)
        {
            string msg = "";
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Product p = new Product();
               

                //productImage

                string webroot = _he.WebRootPath;  // _he comes from IHostingEnvironment 
 
 
                string folder = "Product_Images";
                string imgfilename = Path.GetFileName(productVM.Image.FileName);
                string filewrite = Path.Combine(webroot, folder, imgfilename);

                using(MemoryStream ms=new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await productVM.Image.CopyToAsync(ms);
                    p.Image = ms.ToArray();
                    p.ImageFile = "/" + folder + "/" + imgfilename;
                }
                using(var stream=new FileStream(filewrite, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await productVM.Image.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
                _context.Add(p);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                msg = "Product inserted successfully!!!";
                TempData["msg"] = msg;
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            else
            {
                msg = "Product image incomplete. Please try again...";
            }
            TempData["msg"] = msg;
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I have always used the .net core docs on upload files, here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0#file-upload-scenarios

and

I check it just now also, this particular section https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0#upload-small-files-with-buffered-model-binding-to-a-database should answer your question.

Comment: Please don't use link only answers, as they stop to provide being useful, if the links die or the content of the links change