# How to upload pictures in ASP.net Core Web API and Angular 13

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

**I need to save pictures in the file directory. Data is already being saved in the database. But I want to save an image. I do not have a proper understanding of that**

***Angular Form***

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
            <mat-card>
                <h2 class="fw-bold text-center">Product Management</h2>
                <label class="fw-bold" for="">Product Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" formControlName="ProductName" class="form-control">

                <input type="text" name="description" id="description" placeholder="Product Description" class="form-control mt-3 mb-2" formControlName="ProductDescription">
                <input type="text" name="price" id="price" placeholder="Product Price" class="form-control mt-3 mb-2"  formControlName="price">
                <input type="text" name="created" id="created" placeholder="Product created" class="form-control mt-3 mb-2"  formControlName="created">
                <input type="text" name="cat" id="cat" placeholder="Product created" class="form-control mt-3 mb-2"  formControlName="ProductCatID">

                <input type="file" name="Image" id="Image" class="form-control mt-3 mb-2" (change)="onFileChange($event)" formControlName="ImageUrl">
                <img [src]="imageSrc" *ngIf="imageSrc" style="height: 300px; width:500px">

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-3">Submit</button>
            </mat-card>
        </form>
```

***Angular TS file***

```
submit(){
console.log(this.myForm.value);
this.http.post('https://localhost:5001/api/Products', this.myForm.value)
.subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res);
  alert('Uploaded Successfully.');
})
```

}

**I think there is no problem with the angular part.**

***Web API Controller***

```
 [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult<ProductDto> CreateProduct(CreateProductDto pro)
    {
        try
        {
            
            var productEntity = _mapper.Map<Product>(pro);
            var newProduct = _SqlService.AddProduct(productEntity);

            var productForReturn = _mapper.Map<ProductDto>(newProduct);

            return CreatedAtRoute("GetProduct", new { id = productForReturn.ProId },
                productForReturn);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex}");
        }
        
    }
```

***This is the Model class***

```
 public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]
    public decimal price { get; set; }
    public DateTime created { get; set; }
    public int ProductCatID { get; set; }
    public ProductCat Category { get; set; }
    
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

***This is Create Dto class***

```
public class CreateProductDto
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }
    public DateTime created { get; set; }
    public int ProductCatID { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    
}
```

***This is my SQL Service Code***

```
public Product AddProduct(Product product)
    {
        _context.Products.Add(product);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return _context.Products.Find(product.ProId);
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload pictures to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66165651/how-to-upload-pictures-to-controller)

Comment: I don't think so. I have divided my API into 3 main sections. because of the separation of concern way. I know how to save data but i don't understand how images save using this method

Comment: What issue you are having with?  There is no code for image processing or saving.  Could you please describe your expectation here?

Comment: Thats what i dont know how to implement. i just want to save image.

Comment: Well, seems from your `angular code` your picture is loading but I haven't seen any related code at your backend code for file processing. Anyway, first [have a look at this code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72442567/upload-pic-in-model-asp-net-core/72443710#72443710). If you can implement that then fine, otherwise, let me know if you encounter any further issue.

Comment: Its not working

Comment: What exactly not working? Any error? Could you please share your current code.

Comment: Did you able to post new question with your current concern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I need to save pictures in the file directory. Data is already being saved in the database. But I want to save an image. I do not have a proper understanding of that"

> Well, let's assume we want to upload `product image` in the `image folder` under `wwwroot` within our application. Just like the image
> below:
>
> [image]
>
> The common scenario in our daily development life cycle is, to save
> the image into a desired folder within the application and save that
> `image name` or `image path location` into the database which is the
> best practice so far.

**Your Current Scenario:**

*As per your given code sample it seems that you are sending `picture` from your `front-end` application (angular) by `type="file" name="Image" id="Image"` which seems good. Unfortunately, your `asp.net core` `backend` has no capabilities to receive that picture at this moment. So it would be best if you had a few modifications to your existing code as below.*

**Modify Controller Definition :**

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateProduct(CreateProductDto pro, IFormFile Image)
        {
            try
            {
                //Checking if the user uploaded the image correctly
                if (Image == null || Image.Length == 0)
                {
                    return Content("File not selected");
                }
                //Set the image location under WWWRoot folder. For example if you have the folder name image then you should set "image" in "FolderNameOfYourWWWRoot"
                var path = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "FolderNameOfYourWWWRoot", Image.FileName);
                //Saving the image in that folder 
                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await Image.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    stream.Close();
                }

                //Setting Image name in your product DTO
                //If you want to save image name then do like this But if you want to save image location then write assign the path 
                pro.ImageUrl = Image.FileName;

                var productEntity = _mapper.Map<Product>(pro);
                var newProduct = _SqlService.AddProduct(productEntity);

                var productForReturn = _mapper.Map<ProductDto>(newProduct);

                return CreatedAtRoute("GetProduct", new { id = productForReturn.ProId },
                    productForReturn);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex}");
            }

        }
```

**Explanation:**

**`Firstly`,** your controller signature was like `ActionResult<ProductDto>` seems you are trying to return your `product dto` after a successful response. But `async Task<IActionResult>` can also do the same. So I have modified the signature.

**`Secondly`,** your existing controller parameter was like `CreateProduct(CreateProductDto pro)` which cannot handle the uploaded picture from your `front-end` application request. So to handle that you should have this modification `CreateProduct(CreateProductDto pro, IFormFile Image)` now your controller will understand a `picture property` would be sent from your `front-end` application by name of `name="Image"`.

**Output:**

Once you upload the picture it will save the information into the `database` as below.

[image]

**Note:**

When you would save `ImageName` it will save into the database as `ImageName` on the other hand when you would save the `path` it will save as `ImageLocation` fashion.

Answer (score 0):

From Angular your sending a file while your modal is waiting for an ImageUrl.
The missing part here is a an image saving service (Intercepts the file from Angular, save it in the database, then return an URL (/yourServer/yourProject/pictures/picture01.jpeg). Then you set the returned URL to th DTO object and you persist it).
One of the good ways to save pictures from Angular to the Database is to use Base64 converting like this example: https://www.thecodehubs.com/generate-base64-string-and-display-image-in-angular-12/